# Burninate the google-fit-sdk tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[google-fit-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-fit-sdk) (151 questions) is described as:

> An open platform that lets users control their fitness data. Google Fit lets developers build smarter apps and manufacturers focus on creating amazing devices.

[google-fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-fit) (384 questions) is described as:

> Google Fit is a an open platform that lets users control their fitness data.

There are [<s>only 20 questions tagged with the former but not the latter</s> no questions tagged with the former but not the latter, as I have edited them to add the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-fit-sdk+-google-fit).

The difference between the tags is unclear. The latter tag is better used, and is sponsored. I propose the burnination of [google-fit-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-fit-sdk).

Comment: I support synonimization instead.